# Uploading image as Parse File

Tags: c#, wpf, parse-platform

I am trying to upload a select image file from within my WPF application to be stored on Parse however I cannot find the correct method to do this anywhere.

At the moment I have selected my image from 'OpenFileDialog' and have the path for that image stored within a text box.

How do I now upload this file to Parse?

I am familiar with parse and have no problems saving strings, images, video etc in Objective-C but cannot for the life of me think of how to get this to work in a WPF application in C#.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a piece of code that loads an image file and save the data into a byte array.

```
private byte[] LoadByteArrayFromFile(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[fs.Length];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            int bytesToRead = (int)fs.Length;

            while (bytesToRead > 0)
            {
                int read = file.Read(byteArray, bytesRead, bytesToRead);
                if (read == 0)
                    break;
                bytesToRead -= read;
                bytesRead += read;
            }

            return byteArray;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So you first get the data.

```
byte[] data = LoadByteArrayFromFile(filename); //OpenFileDialog.Path, full path to the image
```

And then, construct [a ParseFile](https://www.parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide) - you should be familiar with the rest steps.

```
if (data != null)
{
    ParseFile file = new ParseFile(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename), data); 
    await file.SaveAsync();
    //then assign the ParseFile into a ParseObject, like the doc says...
}
```

Comment: You are an absolute legend. Thank you very much.